# Opaque TextView within transparent RelativeLayout container

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a RelativeLayout container with a background image and some text in TextViews on top of the image. The entire container has a 95% opacity (0.95 alpha), but I want the TextViews to be at full opacity. I can't make just the image LinearLayout have the transparency because I have two overlapping images in the RelativeLayout (the blue_background LinearLayout, and the blue_bottom_part ImageView) that both need to be at 0.95 alpha (and I can't separately set them at 0.95 alpha, because the overlapping portion will then show up).

I've tried adding

```
android:alpha="1.0"
```

to the TextViews, but this doesn't seem to override the transparency of the whole RelativeLayout container.

I've also tried overriding this programmatically:

```
myTextView.setAlpha(1.0f);
```

None of these have worked.

Here is the XML (stripped down a bit) of the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MyCustomRelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:alpha="0.95">
  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:background="@drawable/blue_background">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/my_title_textview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/my_body_textview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />
  </LinearLayout>
  <ImageView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:background="@drawable/blue_bottom_part"
      />
</MyCustomRelativeLayout>
```

How can I keep the whole container (both background images) at 95% transparency while making the text fully opaque?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if I'm not wrong, you can't do it the way you want.

Instead, I suggest you to use a FrameLayout with an ImageView filling it. This ImageView would have your background with the transparency and you'd put your layout with the TextViews after it, inside the FrameLayout, so that it will be on top of the ImageView.

Please, search about FrameLayout. It'll be easy to do with it.

Comment: Wouldn't that be similar to just putting the alpha value in the current LinearLayout and ImageView? The only problem is I need both parts of these to be 0.95 alpha, but I can't set them to individually have this transparency, because they overlap (and then the overlapped portion shows a double transparency). The background of the LinearLayout (blue_background image) and the background of the ImageView (blue_bottom_part) overlap into one image that I need to have overall transparency.

Comment: If you set alpha in the current LinearLayout, your TextViews will become transparent too. If you create an Imageview with your background (blue_background) and your alpha, and put the rest on top of it with FrameLayout, this ImageView will be the background. So, you put the current ImageView (blue_bottom_part) you have in the bottom. You can set any image in this bottom Imageview, with or without transparency. It'll be on top of the other.

Comment: Makes sense. The only other issue now is that the blue_background is wrap_content and wraps around the TextViews, depending on what the text is at runtime (set programmatically). Now the TextView won't be a child of the blue_background image, so it doesn't know how big to get. Any good way around this?

Comment: Use the same idea. Create a FrameLayout with the Imageview with the blue_background and the TextViews. Make this FrameLayout wrap the content and the ImageView fill the parent.

This technique can be used to set background to any View or group of Views.